# Call python script with php (windows xampp server)

Tags: php, python

Trying a very simple task. Call python `example.py` from a php script from a windows xampp server.

Notes:
- Both files are in the same directory.
- Going to http://example.com/example.py works fine.
- Going throught the command line (cd inside where example.py is then (python example.py)) works also.

example.py

```
#! C:{path-to-python.exe}
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("<html>")
print("<h1>Something.</h1>")
```

index.php

```
<?php
   $command = escapeshellcmd('python example.py');
   $output = shell_exec($command);
   echo $output;
?>
```

Nother note:
- If I use `$command = escapeshellcmd('example.py');` it opens the python script in my text editor.

Someone tell me plz what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What is your default way of opening files with the '.py' extension? If it's text editor, change it to python! You can find it under menu, default apps.

Comment: I seem to have changed the default opening of '.py' to notepad++. I've reverted that to the 'python.exe'. I checked if it works with ($command = escapeshellcmd('python example.py');) but it just does nothing, then like this ($command = escapeshellcmd('example.py');) and it works but it prints out including the 1st line. That does no happen if i go directly to the py webpage.

Comment: Maybe it runs the code in stead of checking the string. try to set the string as variable, then pass the variable into escapeshellcmd

Comment: You need to specify the full path. To simplify for testings, try to put the python executable in the same folder.

Comment: I restarted the xampp a few times an It started to work with the python command `$command = escapeshellcmd('python example.py');`. Now the only thing that is bodering me is that the `print("Content-Type: text/html\n")` still prints out as a string.

Answer (score 1):

to call python script from php :

```
$result=exec("python test.py ");
```

if you want to passing parameters to python script :

```
$result=exec("python test.py param1 param2");
```

in python script if you want get parameters:

```
import sys
param1=sys.argv[1]
param2=sys.argv[2]
```

note : $result in php taking first print statement in python script

Comment: note: if you need to send json file as parameter from php to python you must encode json file e.g... base64 because in send parameter remove all (") from json file